# Showing that the induced map on the quotient vector space is a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, invariant-subspace

> A subspace $W$ of $V$ is called *invariant* under the linear transformation $T:V\to V$ if $T(W)\subseteq W$. Prove that $S: V/W\to V/W$ defined by $v + W\mapsto T(v) + W$ is a linear transformation.

Tried to compute $S(\alpha_1v_1 + W + \alpha_2v_2 + W)$, but couldn't get it to work out. Any direction would be helpful!

Comment: As is often the case with quotient spaces, the important point is showing that $S$ is well-defined. This is where $T(W)\subset W$ is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact that $W + W = W$ and that $\alpha W = W$ for all nonzero scalars $\alpha$.  So, 
$$
\begin{array}{lll}
& & S(\alpha_1v_1 + W + \alpha_2v_2 + W) \\
& = & S(\alpha_1v_1 + \alpha_2v_2 + W)\\ 
& = & T(\alpha_1v_1 + \alpha_2v_2) + W\\
& = &
\alpha_1 T(v_1) + \alpha_2 T(v_2) + W \\
& = & \alpha_1 T(v_1) + W + \alpha_2 T(v_2) + W\\
& = & \alpha_1 S(v_1 + W) + \alpha_2 S(v_2 + W)\\
\end{array}
$$

Comment: So where did you use the fact that $W$ is invariant under $T$?

Answer (score 1):

This is well explained in Chapter 3 of Axler's *Linear Algebra Done Right*.

First of all, one needs

[image]

where the "affine subsets" are given by the following definition:
[image]

Then

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Recall that: $\alpha_1 v_1 + W + \alpha_2 v_2 + W = (\alpha_1 v_1 + \alpha_2 v_2) +W$. So,

$$S(\alpha_1 v_1 + W + \alpha_2 v_2 + W) = S((\alpha_1 v_1 + \alpha_2 v_2) +W) = T(\alpha_1 v_1 + \alpha_2 v_2) + W.$$

Now, using linearity of $T$, can you finish?